# Redirection with reactjs and nodejs is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm creating a login system with React for frontend and Express for backend. I've already created the home, login and register page and when I run the app localy it works fine, but when I upload it to Heroku it breaks, e.g:

if I put this "http://localhost:3000/Register" in the browser, the Register page loads ok, but when I do the same in heroku's app, like this "https://twitterweb2.herokuapp.com/Register" then it breaks, it doesn't load and I get the "Cannot GET /Register" message. I'm concious I can handle this on the server side and it do may work, but why isn't working right now?

This is my React code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import Raiz from './pages/Raiz/Raiz';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import Register from './pages/Register/Register';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Raiz} />
      <Route exact path="/Register" component={Register} />
      <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And this is my server code:

```js
var express = require('express')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const { Client } = require('pg')
const { response } = require('express')

var app = express()

const connectionData = {
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'dblocal',
  password: '123456',
  port: 5432,
}

const client = new Client(connectionData)
client.connect()

const port = 3030;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(express.json());
app.post('/pages/Register', async (request, responsee) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(request.body.password, 10);
  console.log(hashedPassword);   
  const data = request.body;

  client
    .query("select * from usuario where correo = '" + data.email + "'")
    .then(response => {
      if (response.rowCount>=1) {
        responsee.json({
          status: 'user already exists'
        });
      }
      else (
        client
          .query("insert into usuario (nombre, apellido, correo, usuario, passwordd) values ('"+data.name+"', '"+data.lastname+"', '"+data.email+"', '"+data.username+"', '"+hashedPassword+"')")                                
          .then(response => {
            responsee.json({
              status: 'user successfully created'
            })
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("se ha creado exitosamente");
          })
      )
    })
    .catch(err => { })
});

app.post('/pages/Login', async (req, res) => {
  const hp = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
  client
    .query("select * from usuario where correo = '" + req.body.email + "'")
    .then (async response => {
      if (response.rowCount>=1) { 
        if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, response.rows[0].passwordd))
          res.json({
            status: 'success'
          });
        else
          res.json({
            status: 'fail'
          });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you didn't send the index.html to the client so react-router is not doing its job. Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@shayankarimi0078/how-to-integrate-node-js-and-react-js-on-the-same-port-f464627df14f) will help.

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem !

Comment: Please approve the answer.

Comment: sure, but how do I do that? I already voted your answer as useful, isn't that what you mean?

Comment: The green tick must appear which means that the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the job:

```
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  // just send the index.html file and point to its location :)
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})
```

Note that this entry point must be after all of your API resources.